# Sharepoint 2013 ribbon section title text

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

The customer wants to rename "Page Elements" and "Text Styles" to custom titles when the user clicks on the styles item in the ribbon. Changing the titles of individual font styles is fine as it's supported by .ms-rteElement-H1 etc. but I need a way of accessing the section titles. 
I've tried

$("div:containsExact('Page Elements')").text('New Title');

and

$(".ms-cui-menusection:contains('Page Elements')").text('New Title');

in an onload js file but the trouble is that the divs aren't visible until the user opens the ribbon item. Is there a way of capturing the event when the user opens the font style menu and then changing the text?

Comment: Could you post the `html` we're manipulating?

Comment: We're trying to change the text in the div 
<div unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-menusection-title">Page Elements</div>
however it appears that this div is only on the page when the user clicks on the ribbon itemto bring down the font styles